# Multiple Scenario in Excel for Fiscal Years

Tags: excel, forecasting

I have a question regarding creating a forecast in excel. Might be very basic. 
I would like to create a forecast that would compare current year vs past years Actuals , forecast and variance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4HUp.png) In the attached picture I would like the values of Actual and forecast to change as i choose the year. I would also like to compare the data of two years for eg 2016 Actuals Vs 2017 Actuals .

Can someone please tell me how i can do this ? I understand i need a separate sheet with data.

Comment: Once you know where the data is can grab the data based on the value for year in cell `C3` with a simple `Index/Match` or `VLookUp` formula.

Comment: See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @ralph Hi, THanks for the reply. I am not sure if i follow.. Can you type the  formula of what it would be if im comparing 2016 vs 2017 actual with a vlookup

Comment: There is no data in your sheet. What do you want to compare? Where should the formula get the data from if there is none?

Comment: @ralph the data is in another work sheet. I basically want the actuals to populate when i select the year from the drop down. I hope it makes sense

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case the formula is rather simple `=Vlookup(linkedCellToDropDownBoxOnThisSheet,'another work sheet'!rangeWithData,columnIndexWithTheRequiredData)`. Based on the information you have given us this is the best answer we (or at least I) can provide.

Comment: @Ralph, Thanks I will give it a try. Ill update you how it went